# Python Data frame Find and replace column values from a list

Tags: replace, find

I have a data frame with 4 columns. i will typically have 200 or more so rows. i have an example below showing 4 rows as an example. There is a column for account number. this account number may appear multiple times in the column. i have a separate excel sheet with 2 columns, listing account number and account name. I want to replace the account number with the corresponding account name shown on my excel sheet. I cannot manually type out using the replace function for every account number, as there are hundreds of account names and numbers. is there a way i can replace the account number with their relevant account names? or perhaps append a new column showing the relevant account name?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want something like the following (You can get `l1` and `l2` by parsing the excel sheet):

```
import pandas as pd

l1 = [100, 200]
l2 = [1000, 2000]

z = pd.DataFrame({"one": [100,100,300,200], "two": [100,100,300,200]})
"""
   one  two
0  100  100
1  100  100
2  300  300
3  200  200
"""
print(z)

z.two.replace(l1, l2, inplace=True)
"""
   one   two
0  100  1000
1  100  1000
2  300   300
3  200  2000
"""
print(z)
```

Comment: Thanks Very Much. that has half worked. However, although there are values in my Data Frame and in my List 1, it seems to be not replacing all of them in the data frame with values of List 2. for Instance, 6358415 & BC557892 are both within list 1 and data frame column 2. However, they are not being replaced by values in L2.

Comment: Hi there, Thank you so mu8ch. this worked perfect now. i just had to convert the column to string. thank you for your help.